# Flask.SocketIO Fails to send data asynchronously to registered participants when async mode is "threading"

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

EDIT: Updated title as the nature of the problem became more clear

I'm trying to implement a very simple socket.io connection to send broadcast events from a Flask server to a Javscript client. The first server message reaches the client, but no more. On the server side, it keeps calling emit with periodic data updates, but the client never receives any messages after the first one.

Here is the JavaScript client (relevant lines extracted from a React app):

```
var io=require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connect', function() {
   console.log('Connection established');
});


socket.on('message', function(data){
   console.log('Message received');
   console.log(data);
   //only gets called for the first message sent by the server
}
```

And the Flask server code:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
app = Flask(...)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="eventlet")
socketio.emit('message', "Test data", broadcast=True)

#Update function called periodically with JSON data
#of the form {"data": {...}}
def update(data):
    data = json.dumps(data)
    socketio.emit('message', data, broadcast=True)
```

The client receives the "Test Data" message, but none of the messages sent from within the `update` function.

EDIT: I find this code in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/base_manager.py

```
for sid in self.get_participants(namespace, room):
            if sid != skip_sid:
                if callback is not None:
                    id = self._generate_ack_id(sid, namespace, callback)
                else:
                    id = None
                self.server._emit_internal(sid, event, data, namespace, id)
```

In the debugger I see the sid value which represents the socket.io client, when the server sends the original "test data" and when it sends subsequent updates. So the server still sees the client as a participant, with the same ID it had to begin with, and yet the client doesn't receive any of these subsequent updates. If I emit two messages in a row before my update function emits any events, the client gets them. But any events emitted inside the update function are not received by the client.

I thought this was some sort of scope issue, but if the server still sees the client as a participant when events are emitted inside the update method, there doesn't seem to be a scope problem. I also tried the suggestion in one answer to pass the `socketio` object to the update function, and I got the same behavior. I can't understand why the client would not receive events just because the server sent them from a specific function, when the execution context of that function shows the client is still a participant.

This is about as simple an example as I can conceive, and I'm doing the same thing that I see in every example I've seen online. Obviously, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make it work by setting async_mode to True when I create the SocketIO instance on the Flask server.

That is, I changed `socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="eventlet")` to `socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="threading")`

I don't know why it's not working properly with eventlet, which seems to be the preferred mode, as threaded is the last one tried if you don't specify it, according to the docstring.

If I understood more precisely the differences in implementation between `threading` and the other async modes, maybe I could figure out why it only works when I use what the docs say is the least performant mode. Maybe I missed it, but I didn't see such an explanation in the documents, just a vague discussion of dependency differences among the different modes.

Answer (score 0):

I think are you missed receive method on client side...
Please refer [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/)

`socket.on('test', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. I have socket.on('message', function(data){...} on the client, as I showed. Isn't that what I need to receive a "message" event? That's the event I'm emitting on the server side. The client receives it when I emit it the first time and not the subsequent times when called from the update function.

Comment: Sorry to say it but I'm used socket in nodeJS.. are you getting socketio in update function. Try to pass socketio in update funtion as parameter.